# Cron job every 12h and 1min

Tags: time, cron, cpanel

I need to load a file every 12 hours and 1 min, which means, **there is not a determinate time of the day**.

I am using cPanel to run the CronJob and the task (the `wget`) is already working fine and I am just having trouble with the time schedules.

I have tried:

```
Minute  Hour    Day Month   Weekday 
*/1     */12    *    *     *
```

But then realised that this wasn't what I was looking for as it loaded the `wget` 60 times every 12 hours.

How should I **set the times** in order to execute the command **every 12 hours and 1 min**?

What I mean by that is that there should be a 12hours and 1 min difference between every command. Example: first run **0:00**, second run **12:01**,third run **0:02**,fourth **12:03** etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: What would be the reason for a time delay of 12 hours and 1 minute? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using bash:

```
* */12 * * * sleep 60; wget <url>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but that was not what I was looking for. I need a 12h and 1min difference between every command execution which means (12am - > 12pm+1 - > 12am+2etc.). Commands in your code are still runned under 12hours only difference.

Comment: Did you consider using some third-party software instead of cron? Like [http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for example. In the **Entries** section there is a description of **timedelta** option which means _...and then every 30 seconds after the last run..._. Seems like what you need - run a task in 12 hours and 1 min after last run.